Parse Error CSS validator "@media { footer{... a {...}} }"
I'm trying to validate my css file and I get a Parse Error in this line and I'm not quite sure why, I do have all the tags closed, and if i place the  outside of the footer it will change my desired result... What am I doing wrong in here?
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    footer {
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 12px;

      a {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 8px;
      }
    }
  }

I tried to change the sequence of the code and re-write the tags just in case, but the result changes depending on how I write it, besides that I don't really know what could I do to change the Parse error in the validator.

most of the online validator are not up to date. Your code is fine.

The only thing that matters is "does it work?" If it does you can ignore the validator which, as mentioned before, is probably not up to date.

Stylelint supports nesting I believe.

your a tag is enclosed within the footer. You can only do nesting when you are using scss. Assuming this styling is in css.


  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    footer {
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 12px;
    }

    a {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      gap: 8px;
    }
  }




https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting
